# Rethrow as TargetInvocationException error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting this error when i call a non-static Method:

> NullReferenceException RealmRecruitment.ResolveRealmFestival () (at Assets/Scripts/Card Manipulation/Realm
>   Cards/Behaviors/RealmRecruitment.cs:14)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222) Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the
>   target of an invocation. System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke
>   (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder
>   binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo
>   culture) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232) System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115) RealmCardManager.OnMouseDown () (*at Assets/Scripts/Card
>   Manipulation/Realm Cards/RealmCardManager.cs:48*)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Here is the code that calls the individual methods as shown in the RealmCardManager.OnMouseDown () message above which is italicised.
(NOTE: I have stripped out non-relevant code):

```
public class RealmCardManager : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnMouseDown(){     
        Type classType = Type.GetType(CardBehavior);
        ConstructorInfo rCon = classType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object cardResult = rCon.Invoke(new object[]{});
        MethodInfo theMethod = classType.GetMethod("Resolve" + CardBehavior, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);  
        theMethod.Invoke(cardResult, null);
    }
}
```

The above code calls individual Methods based on the string CardBehavior, in this case the Method called is as follows

```
public class RealmFestival : MonoBehaviour {
    public PoliticalProblems pP;
    public void ResolveRealmFestival(){
        pP = gameObject.AddComponent<PoliticalProblems>();
        pP.AdjustHeresy(false);
    }
}
```

Finally this calls the following code:

```
public class PoliticalProblems: MonoBehaviour {
    public void AdjustHeresy(bool increase){
        if(increase){
            GameData.RealmLevels[2] ++;
        } else {
            GameData.RealmLevels[2] --;
        }
    }
}
```

If i change AdjustHeresy to Static then the code works perfectly (of course i make the other changes to the calls in RealmFestival). However I cannot have that Method as a Static.

I have tried putting Political Problems on a GameObject and having it stand alone and it still does not change the error message

Thank you in advance

At the request (and with the assistance of) BatteryBackupUnit I have this as the InnerException:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: 
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.Component:get_gameObject ()
>     at RealmFete.ResolveRealmFete () [0x0001b] in F:\Unity Projects\Online Mulitplayer Code\Assets\Scripts\Card Manipulation\Realm Cards\Behaviors\RealmFete.cs:14
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (object,object[],System.Exception&)
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000d0] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x000eb] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232
>     at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115
>     at RealmCardManager.OnMouseDown () [0x0003e] in F:\Unity Projects\Online Mulitplayer Code\Assets\Scripts\Card Manipulation\Realm Cards\RealmCardManager.cs:49

Comment: what's the inner exception? That's usually the most interesting part of a `TargetInvocationException` ;-)

Comment: I am aware that that is 'trying' to give me the information to resolve this issue but i cannot see what needs to be changed in:
    MethodInfo theMethod = classType.GetMethod("Resolve" + CardBehavior, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

Comment: A [`TargetInvocationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) occurs when one calls a method through reflection, in case this method throws an exception.

The actual exception which caused the `TargetInvocationException` can be accessed by the `InnerException` property of the `TargetInvocationException`. Usually this inner exception contains the necessary information to determine the issue.

So please state the content of `TargetInvocationException.InnerException`.

Comment: I am sorry, i do not know how to find that... i am currently googling like mad to find a quick-fix

Comment: Put a breakpoint where the exception occurs. Then when you have the exception you have a look at the exception's `InnerException` property...
Alternatively add a try-catch around the code which throws and in the `catch(Exception ex)` do `Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);  throw;`

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using reflection here? Why not store a reference to a card-behaviour object or method, instead of storing its name?

Comment: This was under Declaring Method: "System.InvalidOperationException: DeclaringMethod can only be used on generic arguments"

Comment: Finally got there @BatteryBackupUnit
I have added the inner exception details to the initial Question

Comment: Looks like the `gameObject` property throws an exception, probably because the `RealmFestival` object is not attached to any game object. If I remember correctly you shouldn't use constructors with MonoBehaviour classes anyway.

Comment: Without Monobehaviour gameObject.AddComponent<PoliticalProblems>(); does not work

Comment: Only `PoliticalProblems` needs to be a MonoBehaviour. `RealmFestival` does not - it just needs a reference to a game object. As far as I can see, `RealmFestival` could just be a method that takes a single game object argument.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, could you please write up your last suggestions as an Answer so i can mark it correct.

In the end i took Monobehaviour off of 'PoliticalProblems' as well and it worked a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CreatingAndUsingScripts.html%20Unity%20documentation):

> Note to experienced programmers: you may be surprised that
>   initialization of an object is not done using a constructor function.
>   This is because the construction of objects is handled by the editor
>   and does not take place at the start of gameplay as you might expect.
>   If you attempt to define a constructor for a script component, it will
>   interfere with the normal operation of Unity and can cause major
>   problems with the project.

In your case, `RealmFestival` does not need to be a `MonoBehaviour` anyway: all it does is attach a `PoliticalProblems` component to a game object. In fact, it doesn't need to be a class either - a static function will suffice in this case (unless you need to keep track of state - but it looks like that can be done by the `PoliticalProblems` component):

```
public class CardEffects
{
    public static void ResolveRealmFestival(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        var politicalProblems = gameObject.AddComponent<PoliticalProblems>();
        politicalProblems.AdjustHeresy(false);
    }
}
```

It's not clear from your code where the string `CardBehavior` comes from (I assume it's a property of a card object), but if you use an `Action<GameObject>` instead of a string, you can store a reference to a function instead of having to look it up using reflection:

```
public class Card
{
    //public string CardBehaviour;
    public Action<GameObject> CardBehaviour;

    public void ApplyCardEffect(GameObject target)
    {
        // Instead of reflection, we can simply invoke the Action directly - assuming it's not null:
        CardBehaviour(target);
    }
}
```

The card initialization code would change accordingly:

```
//card.CardBehaviour = "RealmFestival";
card.CardBehaviour = CardEffects.ResolveRealmFestival;
```